# Django app engine cannot import name old_dev_appserver

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am trying to use django in appengine. I have followed the [installation documentation](http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) and setup the project. But `./manage.py runserver` command is generating error.
Traceback is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/banglapy/settings.py", line 6, in <module>
    from djangoappengine.settings_base import *
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/djangoappengine/settings_base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from djangoappengine.utils import on_production_server, have_appserver
  File "/home/salman/projects/appengine/banglapy/djangoappengine/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    "Error was: %s" % e)
Exception: Could not get appid. Is your app.yaml file missing? Error was: cannot import name old_dev_appserver
```

how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Google removed the old dev_appserver from the SDK in version 1.9.17. There is an issue on the djangoappengine project about it as well.

https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/issues/95

Comment: thanks for the information. i've seen that. i am trying to find a way around.

Comment: I thought they had workarounds in there? You can download an older SDK or wait for a fix from the project. I maintain NoseGAE and I had to completely rewrite it due to the dev_appserver change. There wasn't a workaround.